# Binance API login

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I have an application which uses Binance API. Now for the users to login, they need to go to Binance, get the API and secret keys and use them for authentication. I wonder if it's possible to prompt them with a login screen, where they can just enter their user name, password and a phone code in order to get in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Binance Login through OAuth2.

As it's written in the docs page, the system is currently not opened, and you'll need to contact Binance to get your app credentials and possibly to discuss use cases, SLAs, pricing, and other params before the integration.

Docs: https://developers.binance.com/docs/login/web-integration